# unable to boot to windows 10 after installing kubuntu 18.04 on second hdd using lvm

Tags: dual-boot, lvm

I installed kubuntu 18.04 LTS on second hdd(sdb) with lvm enabled and after that am unable to boot to windows first hdd(sda)...if I select windows partition it goes to grub-rescue prompt.

I tried boot repair and boot info url is below :

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/MWfzwG54cz/

but no success.

> > sudo fdisk-l

Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disklabel type: dos

Disk identifier: 0x000014e0

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type

/dev/sda1  *         2048     718847    716800   350M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda2          718848  973654015 972935168   464G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda3       973654016  974575615    921600   450M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE

/dev/sda4       974575616 1953521663 978946048 466.8G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)

/dev/sda5       974577664 1851121663 876544000   418G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disklabel type: gpt

Disk identifier: 4A402D48-494A-4846-B971-C568427BBB95

Device       Start        End    Sectors  Size Type

/dev/sdb1     2048    1050623    1048576  512M EFI System

/dev/sdb2  1050624 1953523711 1952473088  931G Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root: 930.1 GiB, 998638616576 bytes, 1950466048 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-swap_1: 976 MiB, 1023410176 bytes, 1998848 sectors

Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes

Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

> > ls /sys/firmware/efi/

config_table  efivars  fw_platform_size  fw_vendor  runtime  runtime-map  systab  vars

If I try

> > sudo os-prober

it returns nothing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Update 1 :
I found a bootable windows USB drive and tried the following commands :

Comment: Update 2 :
I found a bootable windows USB drive and tried the following commands : bootrec /RebuildBcd, bootrec/fixMbr, bootrec /fixboot and also bootsect /nt60 SYS and bootsect /nt60 ALL. Still no success. After doing all this ran boot-info : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/5MTmHrQhf7/......There is a different message : Windows is hibernated, refused to mount.
Falling back to read-only mount because the NTFS partition is in an
unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation
or fast restarting.) Any ideas....Thanks.

Comment: After some research the issue seems to be related following bug : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub-installer/+bug/1767889 Will wait for bug to be fixed.....hopefully soon.